# generate number on pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf

I have an issue when

```js
var v = +this.getField("Invoice").valueAsString;  
this.getField("Invoice").value = util.printf("%06d", (v+1));
```

i try to print a pdf with a invoice number
and i want it to every time i print it generate a new number

[PDF file](https://up.top4top.net/downloadf-6133nq5y1-pdf.html%5C)

Answer (score 0):

You could get a random number of your desired length with `JSON.stringify(Math.random() * 1000000).split(".")[0]`

Comment: i need a sequence of number. For example my invoices starts from 4026 i want it to print 4026, 4027 etc.

Comment: Then you don't need anything random now, do you? Just get the previous number and increment it with 1.

Comment: nope. i tried a code to get the value and add 1 its didnt work also